# Redirection from windows batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, redirect

I am executing following command (cmd) file in windows .

```
FOR /F "delims= " %%A IN ('aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --region us-east-1 --output text --query "AutoScalingInstances[?AutoScalingGroupName=='ecs-autoscaling-group'].InstanceId"') DO aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --instance-ids --query "Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress" %%A > /output.log
```

and forwarding the output to another file.

but surprisingly output log is containing followings, All the intermediate steps also going into the output file.

> C:\Users\229338\git\FinanceManager\Infra>FOR /F "delims= " %A IN ('aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --region us-east-1 --output text --query "AutoScalingInstances[?AutoScalingGroupName=='ecs-autoscaling-group'].InstanceId"') DO aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --instance-ids --query "Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress" %A 
>   C:\Users\229338\git\FinanceManager\Infra>aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --instance-ids --query "Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress" i-03dc571e12dde7905 i-0619c37fea84eeb58 
>   [
>       "172.31.2.101",
>       "172.31.3.66"
>   ]

expectation is to get only final output as 
[
    "172.31.2.101",
    "172.31.3.66"
]

Any suggestion how to alter this script.

Comment: What is `aws`? Anyway, have you tried the two `aws` command lines separately, without any `for /F`loop?

Comment: `@FOR /F "delims= " %%A IN ('…')  DO @aws ec2 describe-instances …` or `@echo OFF` as the first command in your batch-file.